# script Outlook with PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, outlook

I've had a script that I've been using for a long time with PowerShell 5 accessing Outlook. It leverages this:

`Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"`

I can't seem to find an equivalent for PowerShell 7 (.NET Core). Anyone know what I can use in it's place? I have a script written in 7 that I would like to leverage Outlook for. Thanks

Comment: Can't you keep using the regular PowerShell for your Outlook automation script?

Comment: I have a script written in 7 that I would like to leverage Outlook for.

Comment: Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" does not work in PowerShell 7 ?

Comment: Try with the full path to the dll `Add-type -assembly "C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, `Add-Type` in [PS7 can add only .NET Core assemblies by name alone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7.1#description), so you'll have to find a path to the file and use `-LiteralPath`. You can start by looking in one of the following paths:

```
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS\
```

You could look for the latest version with something like:

```
$SearchPath = 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook'
$SearchFilter = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll'
$PathToAssembly = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SearchPath -Filter $SearchFilter -Recurse |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName -Last 1
```

And add the assembly with:

```
if ($PathToAssembly) {
    Add-Type -LiteralPath $PathToAssembly
}
else {
    throw "Could not find '$SearchFilter'"
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @GLaisne! Adding nonstandard assemblies by path works in PS 5.x too, so this approach is helpful when you need cross-compatibility.